# Can anyone help me find a good host that supports MDF file?

Tags: sql-server, mdf

Can anyone help me find a good host that supports MDF file? I have a site that works perfectly in my desktop but when I uploaded it to Arvixe it wont work and I can't get a straight answer from them.
Please I need your help so bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No. Only small operations will use MDF - serious hosts will isolate SQL servers on dedicated machines.

There is a transfer wizard available allowing data upload to a server database.

And you should look for SQL Server Express, not "mdf files". It is a server technology.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with small operations, and there are plenty of hosts who are geared toward those.  But +1 for the advice to look for express versus mdf.

Comment: but how can i transfer my mdf file to the sql server?

Comment: Detach / attach, or use the upload facilities provided by the hoster to transfer the data.

Comment: Even a small hoster - I dont want to have to deal with local expressi nstalls myself. A lot easier to deal with this when you centralize syour sql databases on a number of sql server computers.

Comment: @paul that will depend on the host you choose. Some provide web-based database administration tools, some will ask you to FTP a backup or your MDF/LDF files to their server, some will just create the database for you and then give you ways to update it with your schema/data.